# Map a dynamic object with ValueInjecter

Tags: mapping, valueinjecter

I'm retrieving data with Simple.Data - which maps the database table to a dynamic object.
I want to map the dynamic object to a simple type. I have tried this:

```
var dbObject = Database.Default.LocationStatus.FindByLocationStatusId(locationStatusId);
ILocationStatus domainObject = new LocationStatus();
domainObject.InjectFrom((object)dbObject);
```

But no properties in the domainObject are set.
The mapping *should* be simple as the property names are the same, ei: dbObject.Name and domainObject.Name

Where am I going wrong?
Note: I can in fact magically cast (duck typing?) (LocationStatus)dbObject but I'd like to know how to map with ValueInjecter. Thanks.

Comment: it should work if the properties have the same name and type, look here: http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/discussions/240346

Comment: Ye, that's where I got the original code. I must be missing something. Thanks for your help chuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange as it may sound, I ran into this same problem a few days ago, and the solutions was simple.

You need to cast the output of your dynamic to the type your trying to map too.

In my case:

```
WeatherData myData = new WeatherData().InjectFrom((object)weatherData);
```

as shown in the post referenced in the comments above didn't work (I suspect with the same problem as the original poster), but when cast using as ...

```
WeatherData myData = new WeatherData().InjectFrom((object)weatherData) as WeatherData;
```

Everything works fine.

So it seems even with the newer versions, 3+ years later this can still be an issue, and casting the output type is the fix.